# Remove only double letters sequences in word with best speed with python

Tags: python, regex, string

Very popular task for finding/replacing double letters in a string. But exist solution, where you can make remove double letters through few steps. For example, we have string `"skalallapennndraaa"`, and after replacing double letters we need to get in output `"skalpendra"`. I tried solution with

```
re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1', "skalallapennndraaa")
```

, but this don't remove all double letters in a string(result- `"skalalapendra"`). If I use `r''` as second parameter, I got a closely related result `"skalaapendr"`, but I still can't find right regular expression for replacement parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to run the regex multiple times until you replace nothing.

Comment: Problem in replacement parameter, because in places when double letters needs to be removed, r'\1' leaves 1 letter, but I need to remove both(and only 2) letters, not 3 or any other number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this double replacement:

```
>>> s = 'skalallapennndraaa'
>>> print re.sub(r'([a-z])\1', '', re.sub(r'([a-z])([a-z])\2\1', '', s))
skalpendra
```

`([a-z])([a-z])\2\1` will remove `alla` type of cases and `([a-z])\1` will remove remaining double letters.

---

**Update:** Based on comments below I realize a loop based approach is best. Here it is:

```
>>> s = 'nballabnz'
>>> while re.search(r'([a-z])\1', s):
...     s = re.sub(r'([a-z])\1', '', s)
...
>>> print s
z
```

Comment: *after replacing double letters we need to get in output "skalapendra"*. You have `skalpendra` as output.

Comment: It seems just that I need. Thank you!

Comment: It was my mistake in description, that output is right.

Comment: Works for the example, but in general you'd need to keep applying the regex until the result stops changing, not just two cycles.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I need do it in the cycle until all double letters sequences will be removed in the string.

Comment: @tdelaney: I was going to post a loop based solution initially but then I couldn't think of an example where this 2 phase approach won't work.

Comment: @anubhava - good point! You have to go fairly far out ... like 'nballabn'.